# JavaScript events of contenteditable DIV

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I'm building a website where you can post a message to the forum. First I had a `<textarea>` where the user could type their post, but I wanted a rich text editor.
I stumbled upon the `contenteditable`-property which I am now using. But instead of a `<textarea>` it is a `<div>`.

I want to show the user a preview of what's being posted, just as I see now while I am typing this question.
For the `<textarea>` I used the JavaScript-events `onkeyup` and `onkeypress`, but that doesn't seem to work for a `<div>`.

Now is my question, how would I go about tracking changes in the `innerHTML` of the `<div>`? I don't want to use jQuery for this, just JavaScript.

EDIT// Okay, this is embarrassing. `onkeyup` and `onkeypress` just work for `div`s, but I had a typo in the `getElementById`-id.

Comment: `Onkeyup`  and `onkeypress` should work for a div element.

Comment: Mouser is correct. Key events definitely work for contenteditable elements.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It wasn't working because I had a type in my code, see the edit. Anyway, thanks for helping and pointing it out!